# React native android dark mode issue

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

When i change my mobile theme from light to dark it is affecting the background color of my react native app. I just want it to always remain white but it changes white to black when i change my mobile theme from light to dark.
Android version 10
React native version 0.61.5
React version 16.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom background to the entire container you have at the root and you should be good.

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  }
})
```

Comment: this is happening in only android 10 which supports dark mode.. it is nothing related to react native stylesheet. we need to change in native android which is in java to support only light theme